# How do I farm effectively as a lone Assassin (Zero)?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been following this site for months, yet haven't ever seen any legit experience farming techniques for the Assassin, *unless coupled with teammates*.

I'm a level 48 in TVHM, trying to level up a bit quicker. I don't have friends playing on console so I'm on my own, meaning most of these tactics and techniques aren't useful for me.

I can't find any when searching, either, all I find is the methods for Sal, etc. So what tactics and strategies should I be taking for experience farming as a lone Assassin?

Comment: I'd suggest farming the Warrior if your character is strong enough. Both good xp and you'll be getting good drops at the same time. I found that if you drop down from the ledge into his arena and just stay there, he can't hit you with any attacks, letting you chip at his HP. Just hit his crit locations on his sides.

Comment: Yeah, there is also a good spot over to the very left of his arena. Problem is, I'm not to that point in TVHM yet and am struggling to get there at such a low level. Would it be advantageous to go back to normal mode and farm the Warrior?

Comment: I just beat him yesterday on normal at level 37, he was 34(?) and i got 14,400 XP. Can't say how much you would get at your level though but it's worth a shot. Other than that just complete a bunch of the side quests. They can be tiresome if you've already gone through them before on normal, but the XP they give is better than just farming mobs.

Comment: Thanks man! Sometimes the daily grind is what works the best. :) +1 for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pretty much only play solo, and I've got a level 72 zer0 and he is absolutely a blast. I've found that the most efficient way to play him for me was pure melee, especially for farming.

I've found two shield/gun combos to be effective and i'll go over them both.

The first is the law/order combo. You can get both of these for doing easy quests in sanctuary near the end of the main storyline. No killing of enemies required. The order is a shield that gives a pretty large boost with roid damage, and when you melee enemies with the law all damage you do to them also heals you.

The second is the rubi/love thumper combo. You get the rubi as a quest reward from moxxi for turning the "rakkaholics anonymous" quest in to her. the love thumper you'll get as a quest reward in overlook for doing the "best mothers day ever" quest. The best rubi to get is a slag rubi, if you have the time to spend farming the quest to get one. 12% of all damage you do with the rubi returns to you as health, and the love thumper is a pretty strong roid shield that also does explosive damage when depleted.

The reason you'll want either of these combos is because they heal you while you're in combat, and healing is one of the main things missing as a skill from Zer0's skill tree. This means you can get right up in the face of anything, and as long as you can hit them, you can generally let them wail on you without going down.

As for a build, i'd suggest going with [this one](http://www.bl2skills.com/assassin.html#000000000005050100005505515051).

and as you level up, try to work down the cunning tree to get death blossom (if you have the dlc's that let you level up past level 50). many must fall + death blossom in tandem is incredibly powerful.

the main strategy with this build is getting up in the face of what you are fighting, hit it to apply deathmark, let it take down your shield (so you get the roid damage buff and make counter-strike active), go into deception and get behind the enemy (hitting from behind activates ambush/backstab), wait until the deception timer is under 1 second left (to get the max melee damage boost from deception), and then smacking them with execute. it takes a good bit of practice, some set up, and some skill - but once you get the basic concept down... zer0 becomes VERY powerful. especially once you get the health of a major enemy down to ~30% when killing blow kicks in. if your enemy is slagged, you will be hitting them for MILLIONS each melee blow. one more point, is to try to go for critical hits as much as you can as they will basically double the damage you are doing.

if you have any more questions about anything specific - let me know. zer0 is probably one of the strongest solo players in the game, but he does require a little bit of equipment and practice to get that way

Comment: Wow!!! Ha I knew Zero had some serious potential, just didn't know melee could be so advantageous. I was able to procure a Bee shield and have been having way too much fun sniping, but I'll for sure try your setup. I love his stealth aspect. I'll look into it all :D thanks, my friend. +1 for being a bad ass. haha

Comment: I do have one question...the Unf0reseen skill, did you find it useful? The respec you showed doesn't have any points allotted to it...is it a help or a hindrance with the melee tactic?

Comment: you'd be better off putting your last two points in rising shot to boost your damage output, unforeseen is okay in NVHM/TVHM but doesn't scale well in UVHM so I haven't used it in forever, ha.

Comment: also, everybody goes through their bee phase haha. but really, i'd totally avoid it for zer0 as pistol zer0 builds just can't even come close to the badassness of a full melee zer0. keep the bee on a siren/axton to make better use of it. i struggled through the first half of the second playthrough with zer0 because i was trying to run a gun build. once i went full melee, i never looked back!

Comment: Right on. I'll get to work on perfecting my crowd management. As I work my way up into UVHM I'm sure I'll enjoy the melee concept more and more. Thanks for the input!!!

Answer (score 0):

All characters and their associated builds have an ideal target to farm for XP. For melee Zer0, Mick Zaford is a great choice. To do this:

1. Complete the whole clan wars series of missions except the last one (get up to the point where you choose which side to kill).
2. Go to Lynchwood, unlock the fast travel and do some setup i.e. make sure the second weapon you equip is the one you want in your hands when you kill Mick (like the rapier).
3. Use the (NOT fast) travel and go to The Dust, you should spawn right next to Mick and can instakill him (because melee Zer0 is strong).
4. Immediately after killing Mick, Save+Quit, and do it again over and over until your are the desired level.
5. When the desired level is reached, Save+Quit to reset Mick, then just leave. This ensures Mick doesn't die and you can farm him again later.

Hope that's a good answer for you and others.